# drawing a stack frame for recursive function

Tags: c, assembly, stack

Given the following recursive function :

```
int silly(int n, int *p)
{
    int val, val2;

    if (n > 0) {
        val2 = silly(n << 1, &val);
    } else {
        val = val2 = 0;
    }

    *p = val + val2 + n;

    return val + val2;
}
```

Without the optimizer enabled, this yields the following assembly code:

```
silly:
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $32, %rsp
movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
cmpl    $0, -20(%rbp)
jle     .L2
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
leal    (%rax,%rax), %edx
leaq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rsi
movl    %edx, %edi
call    silly
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
jmp     .L3
.L2:
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
.L3:
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
addl    %eax, %edx
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
addl    %eax, %edx
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movl    %edx, (%rax)
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
movq    %rbp, %rsp
popq    %rbp
ret
```

Could someone assist me in drawing the stack frame used in this function, indicating where the program values are stored and where
the `%rsp` and `%rbp` registers point just before the recursive call to
`silly(`) ?

Comment: Assist, yes, do it for you, no. Show what you figured out.

Comment: Hint 1: it looks like the arguments are being passed in registers. Hint 2: there are 4 unique offsets being used with `(%rbp)`, and you've got 2 args and 2 local variables.

Comment: In x86/64, the first _six_ arguments are passed in registers [i.e. not on the stack] and this is true regardless of optimization.  If you look closely, that's why the first two arguments come from `%edi` and `%rsi` respectively. And, in the bottom diagram, flip the order of `%rbp` and `return address` [they're wrong].

Comment: this isn't machine code, but assembly code

Answer (score 1):

So here is the final answer :

```
    |                                |  
    +--------------------------------+
    |                                |  
    +--------------------------------+
    |             ...                |  
    +--------------------------------+
    |        return address          |  12
    +--------------------------------+
    |        return address          |  8
    +--------------------------------+
    |             %rbp               |  4
    +--------------------------------+
    |             %rbp               |  0
    +--------------------------------+
    |             val2               |  -4
    +--------------------------------+
    |             val                |  -8
    +--------------------------------+
    |                                |  -12
    +--------------------------------+
    |                                |  -16
    +--------------------------------+
    |              n                 |  -20
    +--------------------------------+
    |                                |  -24
    +--------------------------------+
    |              p                 |  -28
    +--------------------------------+
    |              p                 |  -32
    +--------------------------------+
```